Find the solution of the differential equation $z(z+y^2)dx + z(z+x^2)dy - xy(x+y)dz = 0$.
I have verified its integrability but since the equation is not homogeneous, I am stuck in arriving at the final solution. Also if the given differential equation is integrable, why can't we proceed with $\phi(x) = Pdx + Qdy + Rdz$ and equate the partial derivative of $\phi$ w.r.t $x$ to be equal to P, $\phi$ w.r.t $y$ to be equal to $Q$ and so on?
I have tried the latter method but arrived at an inconsistency where a function of $z$ alone in L.H.S. equals some function of $z$ plus a function of $x$ and $y$. Can anyone please help? Thanks.

The equation is quasi-homogeneous, i.e. invariant under $x\to cx, y\to cy, z\to c^2z$. If you want to make it homogeneous, make a substitution $z=w^2$. Or directly use quasihomogeneity, divide $\phi$ by $xP+yQ+2zR$ and get a total differential.

This differential equation is not integrable since ${\rm curl}\ (P,Q,R)\not=(0,0,0)$, but one can find a integral factor $\mathbf{\phi(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{z^2(x+y)^2}}$, i.e.,
$$
  {\rm curl}\ (z(z+y^2)\phi, z(z+x^2)\phi, -xy(x+y)\phi)=(0,0,0).
$$
By direct integration, we obtain that the solution $S(x,y,z)$ to initial equation satisfies
$$\begin{aligned}
  S(x,y,z) =&\ \int P\phi dx + f(y,z) = -\frac{y^2+z}{(x+y)z} + f(y,z)\\
   =&\ \int Q\phi dy + g(z,x) = -\frac{x^2+z}{(x+y)z} + g(z,x)\\
   =&\ \int R\phi dz + h(x,y) = \frac{xy}{(x+y)z} + h(x,y).
\end{aligned}$$
Hence, $f(y,z)-g(z,x) = \frac{y-x}{z}$. Assume that $f(y,z)=\frac{y}{z}, g(z,x)=\frac{x}{z}$, and one gets $h(x,y)=-\frac{1}{x+y}$, which is well-defined.
Therefore, we obtain a solution to initial equation as following
$$
  S(x,y,z) = \frac{xy-z}{z(x+y)}+C.
$$
